# How to leave in the first list elements that have a even occurrences in the second list? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have example on haskell:

```
import Data.List
list1 = [-1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = [-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]

func = [x | x <- list1, elem x [y | y <- list2, even (length (elemIndices y list2))]]
```

Result is `[-1, 2, 2, 4]` (This is correct result and want Prolog code give me same result)

First, "elemIndices" get lists `[-1, -1], ..., [2, 2], ..., [3, 3, 3], ..., ..., [4, 4, 4, 4], ...,` then "length" give us length of list, then "even" tells us whether the length is even or odd and then "elem" check if elements x (list1) are in lists that we have collected.

So I have:

```
list1 = [-1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = [-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

And want result:

```
Result = [-1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Any ideas on this or suggestions how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between "*the length is two*", and "the length is *divisible by* two".

Comment: I know, I think, I need to delete that code to not distract people (because it first was not for this task), I want to write like `if elem % 2 == 0:`, but I am not "flexible" with Prolog, so ask for a help.

Comment: Just use `0 is Nl mod 2` with `Nl` the lenght of your list.

Comment: Can you show me how do I need to implement this? Thanks anyway for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haskell solution is wrong: `5`, `6`, and `7` each have 0 occurrences in the second list, and 0 is even, so they should occur in the solution.

As for a Prolog solution, you must keep in mind that Prolog is not an expression-based language, you cannot easily nest expressions the way you can do in Haskell. Instead you must decompose your program into elementary steps and put those parts together to a whole. This can be tedious, but among other things it allows you to cleanly tackle subproblems one by one and to test them.

So let's start with collecting occurrences of an element in a list:

```
% list_element_occurrences(List, Element, Occurrences).
% Occurrences is a list of occurrences of Element in List
list_element_occurrences([], _Element, []).
list_element_occurrences([Element|Elements], Element, [Element|Occurrences]) :-
    list_element_occurrences(Elements, Element, Occurrences).
list_element_occurrences([X|Elements], Element, Occurrences) :-
    dif(X, Element),
    list_element_occurrences(Elements, Element, Occurrences).
```

Does this do what we expect?

```
?- list_element_occurrences([-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], -1, Occurrences).
Occurrences = [-1, -1] ;
false.

?- list_element_occurrences([-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 3, Occurrences).
Occurrences = [3, 3, 3] ;
false.
```

Looks OK, let's continue. What we're really interested in is not the list of occurrences but whether the number of occurrences is even or odd:

```
% list_element_even_occurrences(List, Element).
% Element occurs an even number of times in List.
list_element_even_occurrences(List, Element) :-
    list_element_occurrences(List, Element, Occurrences),
    length(Occurrences, NumberOfOccurrences),
    NumberOfOccurrences mod 2 =:= 0.
```

Tests:

```
?- list_even_occurrences([-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 3).
false.

?- list_even_occurrences([-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 4).
true ;
false.
```

Good. Let's also do the dual:

```
% list_element_odd_occurrences(List, Element).
% Element occurs an odd number of times in List.
list_element_odd_occurrences(List, Element) :-
    list_element_occurrences(List, Element, Occurrences),
    length(Occurrences, NumberOfOccurrences),
    NumberOfOccurrences mod 2 =:= 1.
```

It's not really necessary to construct the intermediate list and then calculate its length; we could just count elements directly. You can do this simplification later if you wish. Prolog is different from Haskell in that Haskell doesn't actually allocate the entire list before calculating its length.

Anyway, now we just need to use these predicates to see which elements we should pick out of a list (I'm not happy about the naming here):

```
% list_list_even_occurrences(List, List2, EvenOccurrences).
% EvenOccurrences is the list of elements of List that occur in List2 an even
% number of times.
list_list_even_occurrences([], _List2, []).
list_list_even_occurrences([X|Xs], List2, [X|EvenOccurrences]) :-
    list_element_even_occurrences(List2, X),
    list_list_even_occurrences(Xs, List2, EvenOccurrences).
list_list_even_occurrences([X|Xs], List2, EvenOccurrences) :-
    list_element_odd_occurrences(List2, X),
    list_list_even_occurrences(Xs, List2, EvenOccurrences).
```

And this gives:

```
?- list_list_even_occurrences([-1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], EvenOccurrences).
EvenOccurrences = [-1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] ;
false.
```

*Now* you could think about replacing the definition of `list_list_even_occurrences/3` with a `findall/3`-based one, and possibly expanding the auxiliary predicates inline as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you make a check that looks like:

```
length(Zs0, N)
```

this thus means that you specify that the number of elements should be *equal* to `N`, not per se even. It is not very clear to me why you use an `N` parameter anyway, since in the Haskell example, you just check if the list has an even length.

An almost literal translation of the Haskell program is probably something like:

```
p(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
    findall(
        Y,
        (
            member(Y, Ys),
            findall(Y, member(Y, Ys), Ts),
            length(Ts, NT),
            0 is NT mod 2
        ),
        Ts
    ),
    list_to_set(Ts, STs),
    findall(X, (member(X, Xs), member(X, STs)), Zs).
```

That being said, as @IsabelleNewbie already pointed out, your Haskell function does *not* give list of elements in `xs` that occur an even number of times in `ys`, it yield elements that occur *at least once* and an even number of times in `ys`. We can update the function to:

```
func = filter (even . length . flip filter list2 . (==)) list1
```

and an equivalent Prolog predicate would be:

```
p(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
    findall(
        X,
        (
            member(Y, Ys),
            findall(Y, member(Y, Ys), Ts),
            length(Ts, NT),
            0 is NT mod 2
        ),
        Zs
    ).
```

Comment: It returns false (

Comment: @AlexGel: I've tested this with: `?- p([-1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], Zs).`

Comment: `?- p([-1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [-1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], EvenOccurrences).
false.` here as well. Either both @AlexGel and I made a copy and paste mistake or you did ;-)

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: yes, somehow the version in the editor and the one in the interpreter are different :)